# SFX Ghetto Kids

Tags: sfx

Anybody know where to find some SFX of ghetto kids?

I mean like children from ages 6-15 that are from the more urban or "street" areas of the city.  The "harder" side of life.

Kids on a school bus that are throwing things at the teachers.

Comment: Bit of context please. Your description is way too general for anyone to understand what you are after. 

Comment: Try looking on Sounddogs.com or Audiosparx.com. But it sounds specific enough that it might have to be custom-built.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Colin--I have cruised through Sounddogs and Audiosparx and there wasn't what I wanted.  I guess we just found a hole in the sound effects market

Comment: I can do a really good impersonation of this type of speech. Let me know if you want me to record something for you.

Comment: @Utopia that would be great, Utopia, I would really appreciate that.  Plus it's a great idea.  My email is chrisnealysound@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be more specific, maybe I can get what you want? I live in Chicago.

Comment: Really I am interested in street kids going to school I guess.  Or a classroom in a city school.  People who speak with that accent and are between the ages 6-15.

Comment: Hey it doesn't look like I'm going to have any luck getting out to a school very soon. Sorry.